# Reference for $L$-functions

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions

What will be a good reference to study $L$-functions for a beginner? Is there any book/lecture note in complex analysis that covers it?

Comment: You should download them all : "Edwards H.M. Riemann#s Zeta function (Dover, 2001)(ISBN 0486417409)(600dpi)(K)(T)(O)(329s)_MT_ (1).pdf",  "Titchmarsh E.C. The theory of the Riemann zeta-function (2ed., Oxford, 1986)(T)(418s)_MCsf_.pdf", "Ivaniec H., Kowalski E. Analytic number theory (2004)(KA)(T)(610s)_MT_.pdf", "Serre-Course in Arithmetic.pdf". If you want zeta functions of curves, it is different : "Milne J.S. Elliptic curves and algebraic geometry. Math679 U Michigan notes (draft 1996)(163s).pdf"

Comment: And many people will recommend http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/IntrodAnalyticNTApostol.pdf it covers everything but good luck for understanding the proofs